# Arrange people in a "table"

Tags: html, css

I need to arrange a list of people in the following order
[image]

the green is the director, the blue and gray: people of 2 departments

Constraints:

- all elements should be of the *same size*, contained in the *same parent* container;
- the table should not contain more than 2 rows;
- the parent width is variable/unknown;
- the fist (green) element is the director;
- the following are:

  - x elements of the first (blue) department and
  - y elements of the second (gray) one.

The CodePen is [here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/dwOXre)

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 220px;}
article { width: 50px; max-height: 50px;min-height: 50px; background: gray; display: inline-block; border: 1px dotted;}
.dir {background: green; display: table-cell;margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;}
.d1 {background: lightblue;}
.d2 {background: lightgray;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <article class="dir">lft mid</article>
    <article class="d1">d11</article>
    <article class="d1">d12</article>
    <article class="d1">d13</article>
    <article class="d2">d21</article>
    <article class="d2">d22</article>
</div>
```

Some explanations:
I have a company director, and commercial and executive staff boxes. The director should head people in the left, vertically centered. commercial people are in the upper line, executive in the bottom one. Boxes should have the same size. Also, as I do an Angular foreach to obtain elements, all boxes should be directly in the "container" parent.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you're trying to do. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I am not sure to understand either. The green box should be the same size as the other and centered, and the grey and blue boxes should be aligned to the right ? Do you have to use a table or can you use something else ?

Comment: I have a company director, and commercial and executive staff boxes. The director should head people in the left, vertically centered. commercial people are in the upper line, executive in the bottom one. Boxes should have the same size. Also, as I do an Angular foreach to obtain elements, all boxes should be directly in the "container" parent.

Comment: I'd suggest that you're using the wrong layout for this (especially since a company hierarchy is not, typically, tabular data); I'd recommend using CSS grid: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1km5fd7w/).

Comment: If the layout is necessary we can style it the same way. I have updated the example in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 Grid layout, define 2 explicit rows 50px-tall and implicit columns 50px-wide each, then add the following constraints to grid items:

- director spans the 2 rows (from top of 1st one to end of last one) and is forced into the 1st column
- .d1 articles are on the 1st row
- .d2 articles on the 2nd row

That's it, no 3rd row possible if you add items but they'll overflow on the right from your fixed 220px-wide grid container. It's up to you to decide if you need an MQ, an horizontal scrollbar or let it overflow.
A 2nd director would surimpose to the existing one but it should be fine with your requirements. Else, remove that `grid-column: 1` and keep the 1st one as 1st grid item if you want it leftmost.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 220px;
}

.dir {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.d1 {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.d2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

article { border: 1px dotted; }
.dir {background: green;}
.d1 {background: lightblue;}
.d2 {background: lightgray;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <article class="dir">lft mid</article>
    <article class="d1">d11</article>
    <article class="d1">d12</article>
    <article class="d1">d13</article>
    <article class="d2">d21</article>
    <article class="d2">d22</article>
</div>
```

⇒ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVBmoG)**

Comment: interesting approach, fix the `.dir {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;  
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle to include all elements directly as a parent to the container.

```css
      .container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 220px;}
article {width: 50px;max-height: 50px;min-height: 50px;background: gray;display: block;border: 1px dotted;}
.dir {background: green;margin-bottom: auto;float: left;margin-top: 25px;}
.d1 {background: lightblue;margin-left: 0px;float: left;}
.d2 {background: lightgray;margin-left: 0px;float: left;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <article class="dir">lft mid</article>
    <article class="d1">d11</article>
    <article class="d1">d12</article>
    <article class="d1">d13</article>
    <article class="d2">d21</article>
    <article class="d2">d22</article>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. the green square is not centered, but pushed ftom top at 25px...